# How can I create a SELECT EXISTS (subquery) with jOOQ?

Tags: sql, mariadb, jooq

I want to build and execute a query like this with jOOQ.

```
SELECT EXISTS( subquery )
```

For exemple:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM icona_etiqueta WHERE pvp IS NULL AND unitat_venda = 'GRAMS')
```

How can I do it? Can it be done?

Comment: Another case of the user knowing how to write the SQL, but the 3rd party software gets in the way?

Comment: Yes, but much less often than with any related software I've seen. I've actually thought to myself "Oh look, I have to Google something about jOOQ again, it's been a while" 1.5 minutes before finding this SO question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found it. I was looking for a `selectExists` method and got confused by the `DSL.exists()` predicate constructor.

There is a much more convenient `fetchExists(subquery)`.

My specific example is resolved like this:

```
create.fetchExists(
        create.selectOne()
              .from(ICONA_ETIQUETA)
              .where(ICONA_ETIQUETA.PVP.isNull(),
                     ICONA_ETIQUETA.UNITAT_VENDA.eq('GRAMS'))
    );
```

Which directly returns a boolean.

Answer (score 11):

[Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221644/521799) is the most convenient approach to what you want to be doing. A more general approach is to use:

```java
create.select(field(exists(...)));
```

Where you wrap a `Condition` (created by [`DSL.exists(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#exists-org.jooq.Select-)) in a `Field` using [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Condition-). As of jOOQ 3.9, `Field<Boolean>` and `Condition` are not the same types. This has changed in the jOOQ 3.17 with [#11969](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11969). You can now also just write:

```java
create.select(exists(...));
```

Comment: I am using R2dbc, I have to use this instead of `fetchExists`.

Comment: @Hantsy: That's just convenience for the above, and there's no reactive counterpart for that. Just use what I've described in this answer